# In Telegram, how to restrict the user for downloading the contents if not joined

Tags: telegram

I have a telegram Broadcast channel in which I have uploaded all the work related documents that this publicly available all the members joined in the channel. However, I see that people who are not joined in the channel also will be able to download the uploaded contents in the channel without joining in the Telegram channel. I just want to make sure that people should join the channel first and then they will be able to download any contents so that I can track the members who are actually downloading and using the documents. Is that possible ?

Comment: It isn't related to programming. You should ask Telegram support.

Comment: BTW, It's IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: Hi Sean, Just to understand a little bit, so what is the meaning of joining to a Broadcast channel then? If the non-joining members can access the docs in the Broadcast channel , then what it makes difference in joining and non-joining in a broadcast channel? Can you help

Comment: You can use [getChatMember](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getChatMember-be41688d) method.

Answer (score 0):

With normal Telegram Channels interface, it's impossible to see which users are downloading the files.

As a possible solution, with [Telegram Bots API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) you could make a bot that assigns to each file a [deep link](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) and track who clicks on the link.
But please keep in mind that when an user has a file he can share it anywhere and you can't control it.